# while loop executing one line of code twice

Tags: while-loop, java.util.scanner

Here is my code. it is a simple console application intended to get me familiar with object use. 
`package okei;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner listen = new Scanner(System.in);

    Arg dec = new Arg();
    String answer = "";
    int howmuch;
    Boolean a = true;
    while(a)
    {   

        System.out.println("Drink, Fill, or Look?");
        answer = listen.nextLine();

        switch (answer)
        {
        case "Drink":
            System.out.println("How much?");
            howmuch = listen.nextInt();
            dec.drink(howmuch);
            break;
        case "Fill":
            System.out.println("How much?");
            howmuch = listen.nextInt();
            dec.fill(howmuch);
            break;
        case "Look":
            System.out.println(dec.look());
            break;
        case "Quit":
            listen.close();
            a=false;
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

}
`

Here is the ouptut
Drink, Fill, or Look?
Drink
How much?
10
Drink, Fill, or Look?
Drink, Fill, or Look?

Why is Drink, Fill, or Look being executed twice?

Answer (score 0):

Just change "answer = listen.nextLine()" to "answer = listen.next()"

Comment: It's not executing twice, it's just skipping Scanner#nextLine every time when you are using Scanner#nextInt before it, that's because the Scanner#nextInt method does not consume the last newline character of your input, and thus that newline is consumed in the next call to Scanner#nextLine. Here is the [answer link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)